# How can i prevent external javascript running on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, mobile

Hello iam begginer with javascript and no clue how to do this.

I have this script

```
<script id="rhlpscrtg" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="async" 
src="https://web.redhelper.ru/service/main.js?c=studenteu">
```

and **i want to prevent runnig this script on mobile devices**.

Right now iam using this css to hide div

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#rc-connect {
display: none !important;
}}
```

but it doesnt work on all mobile devices (on iphone works, some androids not).

Comment: `display : none` will not do any harm for `script` tag..They are invisible by nature..Use `server side` script to detect device type and do no include script accordingly..

Comment: I don't see any connection between some css rule and a script that is referenced. What I ask myself: why would one want to prevent that? If someone chooses to use that script, then be it. Why is it an issue of the script where it is used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make mobile devices not load an external JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105588/how-to-make-mobile-devices-not-load-an-external-js)